# Uplink LoRa packets to Fiware via MQTT communication

Tags: mqtt, fiware, lora

I have the ideetron's gateway Lorank8v1 which catches LoRa packets and convert them to UDP.I have installed lora-gateway-bridge on my gateway device which converts UDP packets to TCP/MQTT. 
After that, i send the packets from the gateway to my VM to the port 1883 where mosquitto MQTT broker is listening.
I have also installed Fiware JSON/MQTT Iot agent and the Fiware's Context Broker.
I can see that my gateway's packets are published in topics into the mqtt broker but i don't know what should i do to pass them into my iot agent and the context broker.In addition, the phy payload of my LoRa packets is encoded and encrypted and i have a node js code to decrypt and decode them.
How could i make my system's architecture in order to push the payloads of the LoRa packets that my gateway catches into the Context Broker.

In addition to the above scenario, i would like to ask something. In order to post on my MQTT/JSON IOT agent automatically the payload which is subscribed to the mosquitto's topics,should it be published there as json? For example my gateway publishes the lora payload with some metadata as JSON to the mosquitto broker to the topic gateway/{gatewayid}/rx encrypted with AES 128bit key and encoded as base64.How could i send these measures after to the MQTT IOT agent as encrypted attributes as JSON format? Obviously,it would not be recognized by my IOT agent at the format which have now!

Comment: Use the edit button not comments

Comment: Maybe your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638932/send-lora-measures-to-fiware-iot-agent-via-mqtt
basically you need a translation from Cayene (or similar) to NGSI. A new Agent for that is incoming.